Prisma batch updating query type eror on Typescript project,
I'm building a chat service api with tyepscript and prisma. but I couldn't fix one of my batch updating queries.
the query is when a user deletes account, it's channels and groups get deleted as well as the members. and also for every subscribed user's, it should remove from the list of subscribed groups and channels. but I've got an error query trying to do so
here's the query, (which I'm getting error at)
await db.user.updateMany({
  where: {
    OR: [
      {
        channels: {
          some: {
            id: {
              in: listOfDeletedChannels,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        groups: {
          some: {
            id: {
              in: listOfDeletedGroups,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  data: {
    channels: {   //I'm getting an error on this
      disconnect: {
        id: {
          in: listOfDeletedChannels,
        },
      },
    },
    groups: {   // And this
      disconnect: {
        id: {
          in: listOfDeletedGroups,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});


my editor is showing me this error
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'channels' does not exist in type '(Without<UserUpdateManyMutationInput, UserUncheckedUpdateManyInput> & UserUncheckedUpdateManyInput) | (Without<...> & UserUpdateManyMutationInput)'.ts(2353)
index.d.ts(2213, 5): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type '{ data: (Without<UserUpdateManyMutationInput, UserUncheckedUpdateManyInput> & UserUncheckedUpdateManyInput) | (Without<...> & UserUpdateManyMutationInput); where?: UserWhereInput | undefined; }'

here's the shema model
// schema.prisma
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(uuid())
  email         String    @unique
  username      String    @unique
  name          String
  image         String?
  bio           String?
  password      String
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
  groups        Group[]   @relation("GroupMembers")
  ownGroups     Group[]   @relation("GroupOwner")
  channels      Channel[] @relation("ChannelMembers")
  ownChannels   Channel[] @relation("ChannelOwner")

  sentMessages  Message[] @relation("UserSent")
  recMessages   Message[] @relation("UserRec")
  contacts      User[]    @relation("Contact")
  contactOf     User[]    @relation("Contact")
}

model Group {
  id       String    @id @default(uuid())
  username String    @unique
  name     String
  image    String?
  desc     String?
  members  User[]    @relation("GroupMembers")
  owner    User      @relation("GroupOwner", fields: [ownerId], references: [id])
  ownerId  String
  messages Message[] @relation("GroupRec")
}

model Channel {
  id           String    @id @default(uuid())
  username     String    @unique
  name         String
  image        String?
  desc         String?
  members      User[]    @relation("ChannelMembers")
  owner        User      @relation("ChannelOwner", fields: [ownerId], references: [id])
  ownerId      String
  messages     Message[] @relation("ChannelSent")
}

model Message {
  id           String   @id @default(uuid())
  text         String?
  images       String[]
  emoji        String?
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
  userSender   User?    @relation("UserSent", fields: [userSenderId], references: [id])
  userSenderId String?
  userRec      User?    @relation("UserRec", fields: [userRecId], references: [id])
  userRecId    String?
  groupRec     Group?   @relation("GroupRec", fields: [groupRecId], references: [id])
  groupRecId      String?
  chanSender   Channel? @relation("ChannelSent", fields: [chanSenderId], references: [id])
  chanSenderId String?

  @@index([userRecId], name: "user_receiver_index")
  @@index([groupRecId], name: "group_receiver_index")
  @@index([userSenderId], name: "user_sender_index")
  @@index([chanSenderId], name: "channel_sender_index")
}

I was trying to delete a user, then it's channels and groups, also remove the deleted channels and groups from the user's subscription list
